# VirtualBox "Bridged" network analog in GNS3?

Tags: gns3, bridging

There is "Bridged adapter" network solution in VirtualBox when your virtual machine gets IP-address from your real physical router (like 192.168.1.62). Is there a similar thing in GNS3 (on Linux preferably)? All i found is loopback solutions, which helps with internet connection, but i still can not connect to GNS3 router from any PC in real home network.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *switch* is a (MAC) bridge, so simply use one of those.

The "bridged adapter" is actually a virtual NIC connected to a virtual switch that uses the host NIC as physical interface.